# Can an auto triggered 2010 workflow create a new item in the current list?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, workflow, permissions

**I need a content type workflow that is automatically triggered to be able to create a new item in the current list. Is this possible? I am getting the below error message.**

I have a scenario where I have over 150 different lists that contain similar content but must remain separate. Because of this, I created a custom content type and have workflows associated with it. I know there is a designed limitation for endless loops but I figured if the workflow creating the item was triggered by a change.. then it would work since it can't be an endless loop.. but I guess I'm wrong or I'm missing something.

Please help! Thank you!

**Error Message:** "The workflow could not create the list item. Make sure the list exists and the user has permissions to add items to the list."

***Note**: My workflow has full permission as I have another one creating items into another list and am using owner account.*

Comment: Would you like to tell us a bit more? What is your environment and how is your workflow set up? Screenshots will be helpful.

Comment: I suppose my main question is just quite simply this... if a 2010 workflow is triggered by a change in an item, is the workflow capable of creating a new item in the same list? Or is it restricted from doing that?

Comment: The environment is quite simple... one site, multiple lists sharing same content type. User creates list item in X list, triggers multiple workflows. One of the workflows copies the item to another list, then checks it for a value, if true it changes a value in the item. This triggers another workflow which checks for that new value and if true creates a new item in the current list.... queue error message. What would you like screenshots of?